# Is there a way to check whether app is running in background or foreground using ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am totally new to Ionic. I need to know how to force an app to kill itself when it runs in background and will it still be receiving push notification when app is killed in the background?? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: yes if you are using cloud push then you will receive Notification, about killing the app please check this http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-ionic-application-from-going-to-sleep-in-background/.

Comment: Check out ngCordova's evetns ---> http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/ it may help you :)

Comment: @MohanGopi : Can you give me any link for the cloud push?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [GCM](https://devdactic.com/android-push-notifications/) push example for detail view of cloud push

And for killing the app please look [here](http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-ionic-application-from-going-to-sleep-in-background/).